# jq only show when object doesnt match

Tags: json, shell, jq

I'm trying to set up an alert for when the following JSON object state says anything but started. I'm beginning to play around with conditional jq but I'm unsure how to implement regex into this.

```
{
  "page": 0,
  "page_size": 100,
  "total_pages": 10,
  "total_rows": 929,
  "headers": [
    "*"
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "168",
      "state": "STARTED"
    },
    {
      "id": "169",
      "state": "FAILED"
    },
    {
      "id": "170",
      "state": "STARTED"
    }
  ]
}
```

I only want to display the id and state of the failed object, this is what I tried

```
jq '.rows[] | .id, select(.state | contains("!STARTED"))' test.json
```

I'd like my output to be something like

```
{
 "id": "169",
 "state": "FAILED"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to print out the objects for which .state is NOT "STARTED", just use negation:

```
.rows[] | select(.state != "STARTED")
```

If the "started" state is associated with multiple values, please give further details. There might not be any need to use regular expressions.  If you really do need to use regular expressions, then you will probably want to use `test`.